# Two orders with same guest customer

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

A rare situation has occurred in our project whereby two orders are mapped to the same guest customer in production  environment. However,it is expected that every time a guest user places an order, a new user with guest id is created out of the box.
What should be the test scenario to replicate this?

Answer (score 0):

A guest customer is created with a specific generated uid. This uid is generated like this:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "|" + email
```

In the very unlikely case that for a guest customer with the same email, the same UUID is generated, the customer might be retrieved from the database and assigned a second cart. However this should throw a DuplicateUidException and prevent the following code from executing.

Refer to this method for more details:

de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.customer.impl.DefaultCustomerFacade#createGuestUserForAnonymousCheckout

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.Do you think the user might have done something which would have caused this scenario?

Comment: I do not think so... Maybe the user registered after ordering on the order confirmation page? But afterwards it should no longer be a guest customer... Except if the process got interrupted afterwards... Have a look at: de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.customer.impl.DefaultCustomerAccountService#convertGuestToCustomer

Answer (score -1):

May be these guest user give same email address or your email unwanted character cleaning code made them same.